# Java compared two ordered lists: expected and actual

Tags: java, list, arraylist, junit, compare

I have seen some posts regarding comparing two lists in Java, but none of them relate to ordered lists - I  care about values at certain indices being equal.

Instead of writing brute-force code to iterate through both lists, do JUnit or Hamcrest have any util methods to compare ordered "expected" list with ordered "actual" list?

In my case they are both lists of `String`, but how would this be achieved if they were lists of `customObj` ?

I want to see all differences, not just stop after the first difference.

Comment: All lists are ordered.

Comment: i meant order is meaningful

Comment: [1,2,3] and [3,2,1] only 2 is common

Comment: Then you don't care about order. You care about values at certain indices being equal.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Meet the [<ul>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

junit's assertEquals works on lists, if the members of the list have equals implemented. String has a working equals method, so assertEquals will work for you

Comment: i want to see all differences. not just stop after first differnce

Comment: You should probably mention that in the question! I think you'll need to use hamcrest and write a custom matcher

Answer (score 2):

AssertJ library or Hamcrest amtchers will help you with the meaningful comparison.